# Использование EJB и EJB Lite в Wildfly

Tags: java, java-ee, jboss, wildfly, ejb

Каким образом определяется, какой тип EJB-компонентов будет использоваться в приложении? Wildfly поддерживает и веб и полный профиль JEE 7, а значит реализует и EJB, и EJB lite. К примеру, я хочу настроить приложение так, чтобы в нём использовались только EJB lite, как мне этого добиться?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`EJB Light` представляет часть (наиболее часть используемую) функционала по сравнению с полноценным `EJB`, что по идее должно позволять запускать приложения базирующиеся на `EJB Light` на более легковесных версиях серверов приложений (application server) так называемый [`jee web-profile`](https://java.net/downloads/javaee-spec/WebProfile.pdf). Реализующие `web-profile` сервера можно посмотреть [здесь](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform,_Enterprise_Edition#Certified_application_servers).

`EJB Light 3.2` поддерживает все то же что и `EJB 3.2` кроме:

- Удаленных интерфейсов (remote interfaces)
- Бинов управляемых
  сообщениями (message-driven)
- Эндпоинтов для JAX-WS Web-сервисов
- RMI-IIOP
- Атрибут persistent для аннотации @Schedule (реализует cron подобный
        запуск методов)

> Каким образом определяется, какой тип EJB-компонентов будет использоваться в приложении? То есть, каким образом можно понять/сконфигурировать то, будут ли использоваться EJB Lite или полноценные EJB?

Зависит от самого сервера и от того реализует он полноценную `Java EE` спецификацию (`Full Platform`) или `Web Profile`. Но разумеется если вы используете функции которые не поддерживаются в `Web Profile` то на сервере реализующем `Web Profile` такое приложение не запустится. Так же если сервер реализует `Full Platform` то неважно используете ли вы функцию из `EJB Lite` или `EJB` будет использоваться один и тот же `EJB 3.2 Full API` движок.

---

Судя по [документации](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/Getting+Started+Guide?_sscc=t#GettingStartedGuide-WildFly8Configurations) WildFly web profile запускается по умолчанию, для изменения режима работы (`Full Plaform` <-> `Web Profile`) необходимо запускать сервер с разной конфигурацией.

Например (запуск `Full Plaform`):

```
./standalone.sh --server-config=standalone-full-ha.xml
```

Конфигурация определяет подключенный модули сервера блок `extensions`.
Отличия `Full Platform` для версии сервера 10.1.0.CR1 заключаются в наличие следующих модулей:

```
<extension module="org.jboss.as.jsr77"/>
<extension module="org.wildfly.extension.messaging-activemq"/>        
<extension module="org.wildfly.iiop-openjdk"/>
```

Comment: Вы вообще не ответили на мой вопрос. Я знаю, разницу между профилями и между EJB, я знаю, что мой сервер реализует и веб, и полный профиль. Я хочу понять, как мне настроить то, какой тип EJB должен использовать на сервере?

Comment: Ок, уже ближе к истине. Я подредактирую вопрос, чтобы он был понятнее. Wildlfly реализует полный EE профиль, и я могу использовать все возможности EJB, но, например, я хочу, чтобы сервер запускал компоненты как EJB lite, как этого добиться?

Comment: То есть, никаким способами использовать EJB lite не получится? Может быть мне неверный источник попался, но ведь EJB lite боле легковесные и быстрее выполняются, или я не прав? Тогда почему нельзя использовать их, если мне нужна лишь часть функционала?

Comment: Благодарю за терпение и за ответ, но всё же не могу понять, будут ли EJB lite работать быстрее?

Comment: "То есть, никаким способами использовать EJB lite не получится?" нет почему же сложность в том что у wildfly нет двух версий для web и full и что когда использовать определяется конфигурацией, но как заставить работать только модули web profile я не знаю.

Comment: "Благодарю за терпение и за ответ, но всё же не могу понять, будут ли EJB lite работать быстрее? " У glassfish на мой субъективный вкус web profile версия работает быстрее.

Comment: Про конфигурацию посмотрите вот тут: https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/Getting+Started+Guide?_sscc=t#GettingStartedGuide-WildFly8Configurations. Судя по документации Web profile используется по умолчанию.

Comment: Спасибо, кажется нашёл по ссылке ответ. Сейчас проверю

Comment: Спасибо, я разобрался. В Wildfly всё сделано хитро и умно. Функции EJB зависят от того, какие модули включены. К примеру, если включёна реализация JMS, то EJB могут быть MessageDriven. И так далее. Дополните ответ этим, вдруг кому пригодится.